# Static and dynamic types w/ inheritance -- subtleties in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have this relevant code...

```
public class PokemonTrainer {
    private Pokemon p = new Squirtle();
    private String name;

    public PokemonTrainer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PokemonTrainer pt = new PokemonTrainer("Ash");
        try {pt.fightGary();}

        catch (Charmander c) {
            System.out.println("You were roasted by a Charmander.");
        }

        catch (Squirtle s) {
            System.out.println("You were drowned by a Squirtle.");
        }

        catch (Bulbasaur b) {
            System.out.println("You were strangled by a Bulbasaur.");
        }

        catch (Pokemon p) {
            System.out.println("You survived!");
        }
    }

    public void fightGary() throws Pokemon {
        throw p;
    }

public class Pokemon extends Exception {}
public class Bulbasaur extends Pokemon {}
public class Squirtle extends Pokemon {}
public class Charmander extends Pokemon {}
```

Why is it that this prints "You were drowned by a Squirtle"?

In my reasoning, "catch" is a method, and when an object is passed into a method, the method evaluates based on the object's STATIC TYPE -- that is, "Pokemon", in this case -- this is demonstrated in the below short example:

```
public class PokemonTrainer {
    private Pokemon p = new Squirtle();
    private String name;

    public PokemonTrainer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PokemonTrainer pt = new PokemonTrainer("Ash");
        pt.fightGary(pt.p); // ------------ Prints "Pokemon!!!"
    }

    public void fightGary(Pokemon p) {
        System.out.println("Pokemon!!!");
    }

    public void fightGary(Squirtle s) {
        System.out.println("Squirtle!!!");
    }
}
```

So what's different about these two examples? Why does the first example print what it does?

Thanks!

Comment: this is 1000% **NOT** what the `try/catch/finally` construct is to be used for! They are called **exceptions** for a reason! *"…In my reasoning, "catch" is a method…"* well your *reasoning* is wrong.

Comment: A rather poor attempt at [Pokemon Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308979/exception-handling-question)

Comment: While Jarrod is right, even if a little over zealous, I believe your expectations are right. The first matching handler should be called. It works for me. What JVM and version are you using?

Comment: @TedTrippin: No, the expectations are *not* correct. Which `catch` block is executed is determined by the *execution time* type of the thrown exception.

Comment: Well it's was simply a problem on a past exam that I'm studying for a final; I'm sorry that the author of the exam decided to poke a little fun with the "catch" keyword, I guess. And I'm sorry my "reasoning" was wrong, I haven't been programming for too long. No need for all of that energy, though, it's completely unnecessary. But thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @Jon thanks for the contradictory answer/comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In my reasoning, "catch" is a method

That's the first mistake. `catch` isn't a method, and trying to think of it as if it were is going to cause you problems.

It's a language construct with its own rules. You should read the [language specification section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) or the [exceptions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information.

In short, when you have a sequence of `catch` blocks, the first one which matches the *execution time* type of the thrown exception is executed. (The compiler will prevent you from catching a more-general exception before a more-specific one.)

So if you have:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

then if `doSomething()` throws a `FileNotFoundException` it will execute the first `catch` block (and *only* that one) - whereas if it throws any other kinds of `IOException`, it will execute the second `catch` block. Any other exceptions will propagate up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `catch` isn't a method but a part of the Java language.

But to answer your question, `p` is an instance of `Squirtle`:

```
Pokemon p = new Squirtle();
```

And since there is a `catch` clause to catch a `Squirtle`, it does exactly that.

```
catch (Squirtle s)
```

If this line wouldn't exist, the more general

```
catch (Pokemon p)
```

would handle the thrown `Squirtle`.

Answer (score 1):

While `Pokemon p` is declared as a Pokemon, it is instantiated as a Squirtle with `new Squirtle()`.  Because it is internally a Squirtle, `getClass()`, when called on it, will return Squirtle.class, so the try-catch catches the Squirtle catch before the Pokemon catch is even checked.

This is called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

In regards to your reasoning, `catch` is not a method, and rather is a statement which goes with a `try` block to declare what to do in the case of certain exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the type of the `reference` with the type of the `object`.

Catch is more like a `switch` on the `instanceof` object.

Consider a simpler example

```
String s = "hello";
Object o = s;
```

In this case the reference type for `o` is `Object` but the objects type is a `String` for both `s` and `o` as they are the same object.